# How to get only 1 of each item in elastic search?

Tags: elasticsearch

I do a search in elastic search and get all the items, sorted by the `"prGreater"` field, for example. But I can have it multiple times in the query return.

Is it possible to search for all items but in this return get only 1 of each item?

This is my mapping:

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "name": {
                "type": "text"
            },
            "nmId": {
                "type": "text"
            },
            "pcDay": {
                "type": "scaled_float",
                "scaling_factor": 1000000
            },
            "vlPaperNeg": {
                "type": "scaled_float",
                "scaling_factor": 1000000
            },
            "dhDay": {
                "type": "date",
                "format": "strict_date_time"
            },
            "prBegin": {
                "type": "scaled_float",
                "scaling_factor": 1000000
            },
            "prGreater": {
                "type": "scaled_float",
                "scaling_factor": 1000000
            },
            "prLowest": {
                "type": "scaled_float",
                "scaling_factor": 1000000
            },
            "prUNegoci": {
                "type": "scaled_float",
                "scaling_factor": 1000000
            },
            "prAvg": {
                "type": "scaled_float",
                "scaling_factor": 1000000
            },
            "prClose": {
                "type": "scaled_float",
                "scaling_factor": 1000000
            },
            "qtdCamp": {
                "type": "scaled_float",
                "scaling_factor": 1000000
            },
            "qtdSell": {
                "type": "scaled_float",
                "scaling_factor": 1000000
            },
            "estdPaper": {
                "type": "text"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Query:

```
{
    "size": 100,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": [
                {
                    "range": {
                        "dhDay": {
                            "from": "2022-06-23T00:00:00.000+0000",
                            "to": "2022-06-24T13:33:04.432+0000",
                            "include_lower": true,
                            "include_upper": false,
                            "boost": 1.0
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "adjust_pure_negative": true,
            "boost": 1.0
        }
    },
    "sort": [
        {
            "prGreater": {
                "order": "desc"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Do you want to get only the unique items in the search result, with no duplicate data ?

Comment: @ESCoder Yes! An item is inserted into the base several times, but I need, for example.. the last of each item, sorted by fields `desc`. With `dhDay`, `prGreater`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You basically want to group the items, say by their "name" and then for each group, get the latest item, sorted in descending order by dhDay.

You need a nested top hits aggregation:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "name": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "name",
        "size": 100
      },
      "aggs": {
        "dhday_max": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1,
            "sort": [
              {
                  "dhday": {
                      "order": "desc"
                  }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

THe subaggregation will contain the latest item of a given name, sorted on the dhDay. You can add more fields to the sort or use 'prgreater" or anything else that you may need.

Comment: I need a range of date/hour, to search... Is include that aggregate in my query?

Comment: Yes, I didn't include your "query" as that is already ok. You can add the date range in the "query" and the aggregation will still work. Pls mark the answer as correct if it helps you!